# Virtualenv installing modules with multiple Python versions

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to start a Python 3.6 project by creating a virtualenv to keep the dependencies. I currently have both Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed on my machine, as I have been coding in 2.7 up until now and I wish to try out 3.6. I am running into a problem with the different versions of Python not detecting modules I am installing inside the virtualenv.

For example, I create a virtualenv with the command: `virtualenv venv`

I then activate the virtualenv and install Django with the command: `pip install django`

My problems arise when I activate either Python 2.7 or 3.6 with the commands
`py -2` or `py -3`, neither of the interactive shells detect Django as being installed.

Django is only detected when I run the `python` command, which defaults to 2.7 when I want to use 3.6. Does anyone know a possible fix for this so I can get my virtualenv working correctly? Thanks! If it matters at all I am on a machine running Windows 7.

Comment: have you installed Django to your virtualenv?

Comment: What is `py -2` and `py -3`? It looks like you are expecting it to change the version of python within your env, but I have not heard of such a thing being possible.

Comment: Yes, Django was installed inside the virtualenv. Py -2 and Py -3 are what I was told are the preferred way to start python 2.X and 3.X on the same machine. The commands are provided by python when it is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the interpreter when you create the virtualenv.

```
virtualenv --python=PYTHON36_EXE my_venv
```

Substitute the path to your Python 3.6 installation in place of `PYTHON36_EXE`.  Then after you've activated, `python` executable will be bound to 3.6 and you can just `pip install Django` as usual.

Comment: hey, when I try this it says "the path does not exist". I checked my path variable and it seems like my python3.6 folder is included in it but for some reason the executable is called "python" and not like "python36". Can I just rename it?

Comment: No, don't rename it.  Just use the absolute path to that executable (i.e. include the folder names).

Answer (score 1):

Create virtual environment based on python3.6

```
virtualenv -p python3.6 env36
```

Activate it:

```
source env36/bin/activate
```

Then the venv36 has been activated, `venv36`'s pip is available now , you can install `Django` as usual, and the package would be stored under `env36/lib/python3.6/site-packages`:

```
pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is that `pip` installs things for a specific version of Python, and to a very specific location. Basically, the `pip` command in your virtual environment is set up specifically for the interpreter that your virtual environment is using. So even if you explicitly call another interpreter with that environment activated, it will not pick up the packages `pip` installed for the default interpreter.